# How to create list view with side count like mail

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, label

Am working small Xamarin.forms application.Now i have doubt to how to count and display list items in label 
like email and gmail.
I'm browsing in google various sites i did't get result

[image]

My Xaml code is below how to display count in side bar and i used grid for that sum Xaml.task error will be occur

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:emit="clr-namespace:System.Reflection.Emit;assembly=mscorlib"
             x:Class="vMonitor.Views.HomeListView"
             Title="Home List View"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008">

    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Model}" Margin="20,0,20,0"
                      x:Name="listView"
                      SeparatorVisibility="Default" SeparatorColor="Brown"
                      HasUnevenRows="True">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="20" FontFamily="TimesNewRomen" FontAttributes="None">
                                        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.TabCommand, Source={x:Reference listView}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                    </Label>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding UserID}" FontSize="20" FontFamily="TimesNewRomen" FontAttributes="None"/>

                                </StackLayout>

                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: do you need help with the layout of the UI?  Or do you not understand how to get the count from your model?  What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: I need help to layout of the UI

Answer (score 1):

Then you can use `ViewCell` for List Item.

```
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Padding="15,10" Orientation="Horizontal">                           
                            <Label 
                                 VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                                Text="{Binding ItemName}"  TextColor="#FF1654" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="16"/>
                            <Label VerticalOptions="End" 
                                 VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                                Text="{Binding ItemCount}"  TextColor="#FF1654" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="16"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

You can Bind ItemName and ItemCount. If you want to Display Left Side Image then you can add `Image` at start position in `ViewCell`.

For Expandable you have to use IsVisible Property for that cell.